# If total is invalid, set the field text and border to red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I'm trying to make a validation condition for the field Total. Total project costs is invalid: The maximum sum for Total project costs is 9,999,999,999,999.99. Once it is more than this value, the border of the text and the text would be red. Would appreciate any help.

```
<tr style="height:35px">
  <td> </td>
  <td align="center"><strong>TOTAL</strong></td>
  <td align="center">
    <input class="numeral form-control text-font-md" disabled="disabled" style="width:auto; height:30px" value="" type="text" data-bind="attr: {'title': totalRequestfromNEHToolTip}, value: tRequestfromNEH">
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <input class="numeral form-control text-font-md" disabled="disabled" style="width:auto; height:30px" disabled="" type="text" data-bind="attr: {'title': totalRequestfromNEHToolTip}, value: tnonFedThirdPartyGifts">
  </td>
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <input class="numeral form-control text-font-md" disabled="disabled" style="width:auto; height:30px" value="" type="text" data-bind=" attr: {'title': totalCostShareToolTip}, value: tcostShare">
  </td>
  <!-- <td align="center"><input class="numeral form-control text-font-md" disabled="disabled" style="width:auto; height:30px" value="" type="text"></td> -->
```

```
var TOTAL = ko.computed(function() {
  var total = 0;
  var hasUserInput = false;
  if (tRequestfromNEH() != '' && tRequestfromNEH() != undefined) {
    hasUserInput = true;
    total = total + Number(String(tRequestfromNEH()).replace(/\,/g, ''));
  }

  if (tnonFedThirdPartyGifts() != '' && tnonFedThirdPartyGifts() != undefined) {
    hasUserInput = true;
    total = total + Number(String(tnonFedThirdPartyGifts()).replace(/\,/g, ''));
  }

  if (tcostShare() != '' && tcostShare() != undefined) {
    hasUserInput = true;
    total = total + Number(String(tcostShare()).replace(/\,/g, ''));
  }

  if (total == 0) {
    if (!hasUserInput)
      return '';
    else
      return formatNumber('0');
  } else {
    if (loading == false) {
      sendCommand('SAVE');
    }
    return formatNumber(total);
  }
});
```

Comment: So what is the problem you're having?

Comment: The problem is the border of the input field is red no matter what the value i have. I want  the border and the background field are black as default. It changes to e red whenever the value is more than 9,999,999,999,999.99 @JasonSpake

Comment: I don't see any code here that would even try to apply a red border. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Right now we can't tell if TOTAL is the problem, nor can we tell if it is only problem. You need to show the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the knockout css binding.  here is one where the text and background go red when the total exceeds 10.  https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/57/

html

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number1">number 1</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" data-bind="textInput: number1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number1">number 2</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number2" data-bind="textInput: number2">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group" data-bind="css: {'has-error': total() > 10 }">
    <label class="control-label">Total:</label>
      <p class="form-control-static" data-bind="text: total, css: {'bg-danger': total() > 10 }"></p>
  </div>

</form>
```

js

```
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.number1 = ko.observable('');
  this.number2 = ko.observable('');
  this.total = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    return parseInt(self.number1()||0) + parseInt(self.number2()||0)
    },this);

}


var vm = new viewModel();


(function($) {
  ko.applyBindings(vm); //bind the knockout model
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you Bryan, That was helpful. The only issue i have now is the entry is automatically goes with comma and .00 at the end. when i set the max 9,999,999,999,999.99. since there are commas, it doesn't read it when i put
9999999999999.99 any solution to put in HTML.

Comment: I updated my fiddle to use a currency input mask. and to remove artifacts before callculating total.   https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/59/